# Reinstall ubuntu without losing data

Tags: backup, reinstall, ubuntu-14.04

Hello I ran into some configuration issues on my ubuntu 14.04 because of this I am not able to connect to Internet from any means.

So I want to re install the os. I currently have 14.04 and I want to install 14.10 but without losing the data I have. I have deja-backup.

So what process should I follow to achieve this. Moving data from one machine to another is cumbersome process.  I use sony viao laptop which has only 1 hard drive.

Thanks in advance! !!

Comment: What "data" are you talking about exactly? Do you mean files in/under your home directory?

Comment: Not all but my workspace , pictures and some documents..this all counts to 220gb!!!......

Comment: After a series of increasingly fragile releases following upgrades using the updater, I grasped the nettle and installed a new 14.10 version to the same partition. I made sure I had backed up the `/home` directory, but in the event didn't need it, as it was left untouched (apart from new configuration entries for the re-installed applications). I wouldn't rely on its being preserved, but it saves a lot of copying and merging if it is kept. What I lost were the configurations in the `/etc` directory, and I should have backed this up as well, if only for reference.